# How to take binary tree as a input when the user gives the edges as input?

Tags: c++, vector, graph, tree, binary-tree

Suppose ,I want to take a binary tree as input when user gives just the edges between two nodes as input and how do I determine which one is the root? Since the user may give the root edges at the last stage of the input also.To be more precise suppose the input be-

```
2 4
2 5
3 7
3 6
1 2
1 3
```

Here the root is one which we get to know after drawing the binary tree which looks like:-

```
       1
      /  \
     2    3
    / \  / \
   4  5  6  7
```

How do I construct such a binary tree.If you think that using   array (adjacency list representation) is the answer then sorry , I want to get to the lca of the two nodes also of this tree which can not be done using vector i assume( it will be great if someone comes up with the solution of getting the lca of two nodes by using adjacency node representation).But which I think is not possible at this time. So my request is that please give me a way to create such a binary tree just by taking the edges as input without getting to know the root of the tree beforehand.
Thanks for your devoting your valuable time.

Comment: Ugh... it is really hard to decypher what you say. Unsure notation describing a tree (image may be clearer).

Comment: The root is the vertex with no ancestor. Of course there may be no such vertex or there maybe more than one, in which case it's invalid input (and other types of invalid input exist as well). A simple loop through your input (after you have read it all) will tell you what the root is.

Comment: @john Oh, I am assuming a valid input. For a given list of edges, assuming they are undirected, there can be multiple binary tries with different roots. If we assume that edges are directed, then there can be always a single tree, but then the problem is much easy.

Answer (score 0):

*"I want to take a binary tree as input when user gives just the edges between two nodes as input and how do I determine which one is the root?"*

Do we have a guarantee that in your binary tree every inner node has two children (as opposed to the possibility of having only one child)?

If no - then there are multiple candidates for a root. In particular, any leaf can be made a root.

So, let us assume that inner nodes must have two children. Let us consider the number of occurrences of each node in the edge list.

- Leaf nodes will appear only once in the list, because there is only one edge reaching them from above.
- Inner nodes which are not root nodes appear 3 times in the list. That's because there are 2 edges going down from the node to its children, and one edge reaching the node from above.
- The root is the only node not having a parent and having two children - thus appearing twice.

In your example: 2 4 2 5 3 7 3 6 1 2 1 3

- 1 - appears twice
- 2, 3 - appears 3 times
- 4, 5, 6, 7 - appear 1 time

Thus 1 is your root.

*"please give me a way to create such a binary tree"*

Now, *this* is hard to answer if you do not explain what should be your final representation of the tree. A list of edges is a valid representation, so you do not have to do anything. But obviously you have something else in mind.

Hopefully, since I have shown you that with a trivial counting algorithm you can find your root without actually building any structure, constructing your tree the way you want will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

### 1. Array/Vector (or map)

Each node has up to two children. Recording these makes it easy to *descend* the tree.

But - each node has *only one parent*. Recording this info makes it easy to *ascend* the tree - which is great for finding the root of the tree, or the LCA of to nodes. After parsing your input, your array loks like this:

```
  ┌─┐
0 │0│
1 │0│
2 │1│
3 │1│
4 │2│
5 │2│
6 │3│
7 │3│
  └─┘
```

Now starting from any node - let's say 6 - we see from the array that 6's parent is 3, and 3's parent is 1, and 1 has no parent. If your node keys are not a list of small ints as they are in your example, you would use a map instead.

### 2. Build a binary tree!

The problem you are probably bumping into doing this is that traditionally we work with a tree by holding a reference to its root, and accessing all other nodes from the root - but while you are building the tree from your sample input, not only do you not know the root, you also have tree fragments that only join up into one tree once you have enough info.

All you need is a temporary structure to hold onto the nodes (and thereby, the fragments) until the tree is complete and the root has been identified. Then you can throw away that structure.

Here is some untested code to show what I mean. Beware - it uses raw pointers, it uses `new`, it has no `deletes`, the tree struct should be a class, etc etc. This is just to illustrate the algorithm and is not recommended coding practice.

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct node {
    node *parent, *left, *right;
    int value;
};

struct tree {
    node *root;
};

tree BuildTree(const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& edges) {
    std::map<int, node*> nodes;

    auto FindOrAddNode = [&nodes](int key) -> node* {
        auto node_iter = nodes.find(key);
        if (node_iter != nodes.end())
            return node_iter->second;
        else {
            auto new_node = new node;
            new_node->value = key;
            nodes[key] = new_node;
            return new_node;
        }
    };

    for (auto edge : edges) {
        auto parent = FindOrAddNode(edge.first);
        auto child = FindOrAddNode(edge.second);

        child->parent = parent;
        if (parent->left == nullptr)
            parent->left = child;
        else if (child->value >= parent->left->value)
            parent->right = child;
        else {
            parent->right = parent->left;
            parent->left = child;
        }
    }

    // now pick any node, and walk up to find the root
    // then construct and return a tree object using the root
    // when we exit this function, the local `nodes` variable is discarded
    //    we don't need it any more.
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto the_tree = BuildTree({{2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 7}, {3, 6}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}});
    return 0;
}
```